NameError: name 'client' is not defined. (client discord)
I am getting the NameError: name 'client' is not defined when I run "await client.close()"
import time
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
retrieved_message=None

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("inside on_message")
    
    if message.content.startswith('$athena'):
        content= message.content
        global retrieved_message
        retrieved_message = content
        print("retrived_message ", content)
        
        filename="message.txt"
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(retrieved_message)
    await client.close()


client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN HERE)


The message is being written into the message.txt file. All I want is to close the client discord after saving the message.
